# html element renders as variable name

Tags: javascript, html, dom, reactjs

While attempting to use React.js and maybe or most likely I am doing something wrong? But when I run React.Render() nothing visible renders, however. Viewing the DOM through Chromes console I can see something happen just nothing anything recognizes.

**JSX**

```
/* global React */
var notifying = {};
(function () {
    'use strict';
    notifying = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function () {
            return { isSeen: false };
        },
        _handleDismissalClick: function () {
            this.setState({ isSeen: this.isSeen ? false : true });
        },
        render: function () {
            return ( <div className={'alert alert-success'} role={'alert'}> SOMETHING </div> );
        }
    });
})();

(function(){
    'use strict';
    React.render(<notifying />, document.querySelector('.__content'));
})();
```

**JS**

```
/* global React */
var notifying = {};
(function () {
    'use strict';
    notifying = React.createClass({displayName: "notifying",
        getInitialState: function () {
            return { isSeen: false };
        },
        _handleDismissalClick: function () {
            this.setState({ isSeen: this.isSeen ? false : true });
        },
        render: function () {
            return ( React.createElement("div", {className: 'alert alert-success', role: 'alert'}, " SOMETHING ") );
        }
    });
})();

(function(){
    'use strict';
    React.render(React.createElement("notifying", null), document.querySelector('.__content'));
})();
```

In the DOM the output is

```
<notifying data-reactid=".0"></notifying>
```

can anyone explain to me what I did wrong where so I can stop making this mistake?

Comment: this is written in jsx, but are you compiling it to js anywhere that we don't see?

Comment: Sorry for that, should have included it, edited post to reflect the converted file

Comment: It looks like your order of execution is causing notifying to still be that empty object when render() is called.  Is there any reason for the double closures?

Comment: `"notifying"` vs `notifying` (String vs Object)

Comment: no particular reason for the double closures, outside of being lazy for testing purposes while I work it up. That and to ensure I can trigger this outside of its scope through other non-react scripts while transitioning to a fully react built version of what I have currently.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a `<notifying />` DOM element. Instead, you need to call the [method to create an element](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.createelement), which is then passed to the [render method](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.render).

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"></script>

<script type="text/jsx">
/* global React */
var notifying = {};
(function () {
    'use strict';
    notifying = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function () {
            return { isSeen: false };
        },
        _handleDismissalClick: function () {
            this.setState({ isSeen: this.isSeen ? false : true });
        },
        render: function () {
            return ( <div className={'alert alert-success'} role={'alert'}> SOMETHING </div> );
        }
    });
})();

(function(){
    'use strict';
    React.render(React.createElement(notifying), document.querySelector('.__content'));
})();
</script>

<div class="__content"></div>
```